# converting Javascript variable to PHP variable in two different php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Can some body help me get the current value from this option tag 
    to account.php as a session variable or anything ..

```
// loadsubcat.php This code is for dependent dropdown

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_cmsjob WHERE VesselID= {$parent_cat}");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
    echo "<option value='$row[jobName]'>$row[jobName]</option>";
    }

var javascriptVariable = $('#sub_cat').val();
```

I know this can be solve using ajax but I don't know how.

I will use the `javascript` variable as a reference for a couple of checkboxes      under it but first must be passed as a php variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you ajax will look like this,

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "account.php",// path to ajax file
            data: {javascriptVariable:javascriptVariable},// you can pass values here in key value pairs.
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);

            }
        });
```

You can send n number of key => value pairs.

like

```
parent_cat:100
```

**Next:**

```
echo $_POST['javascriptVariable'];  // <--- grabbing ajax data here


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_cmsjob WHERE VesselID= {$parent_cat}");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo "<option value='$row[jobName]'>$row[jobName]</option>";
}
```

what ever echoed in php file will come in ajax success `data`,

`alert(data)` will alert what you had echoed in php. you can use that in your html file.

Comment: hey sir may I ask if I use the code above and replace url with my page account.php  and data with my javascriptvariable? can I now grab  the  data using either $_REQUEST or $_POST

Comment: change this line in ajax, `data: javascriptVariable , ` to `data: {javascriptVariable:javascriptVariable} , `

Comment: in php use `$_POST['javascriptVariable']`